# how to do domain ip lookup in debian

Tags: command-line, nslookup, whois

I can use a web-service to lookup the IP Address allotted to a website and then do a reverse lookup to get more info. about range of the IP Address to whom it was allocated to.

But from what brief understanding I have, this works well only with high-level domains only and gltds are with regional registries.

For e.g. -

```
$ host stackexchange.com
stackexchange.com has address 151.101.1.69
stackexchange.com has address 151.101.65.69
stackexchange.com has address 151.101.129.69
stackexchange.com has address 151.101.193.69
```

Looking up any one of them gives me -

```
$ whois 151.101.1.69
```

gives me output of one of the CDN providers of stackexchange.com

but if I try the same say gov.in I come up short.

```
$ host gov.in
gov.in mail is handled by 5 mailgw.nic.in.
```

It is only via a web-service I can come to know that gov.in is under apnic and the address range given therein.

Is there any other way to do that from within the CLI ?  To have IP Address range lookups of root domains from within command-line ?

Edit - Giving more info. as asked by Jasen -

https://www.site24x7.com/find-ip-address-of-web-site.html

I gave it indianvisaonline.gov.in as the IP Address I wanted info. on

In turn it gave me

164.100.129.11

which while doing a whois reveals is a range of addresses owned by NIC which is under apnic.

I want to know if there is a way to do this without going to a webpage.

Could the part of https://www.site24x7.com/find-ip-address-of-web-site.html be done

a. without needing that web service or

b. if we need that web service, do it within the command-line without resorting to using a web-browser.

Best scenario would be if a. could be achieved, failing that b. would also be good.

Comment: what web site gave that info?

Comment: @Jasen just updated my question with the info. you wanted.